# Condition for convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For what values of $a$ is the following series convergent?
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-n\sin(1/n))^a$$

I compared it with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty1/n^2\;$ and found that $a\gt 0.5$. Is it correct? If not please tell whats right.

Comment: You are (almost) correct! You compare it with the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^{2a}}$, which is convergent if and only if $2a>1.$

Comment: Thanxx i actually compared this series only ..